# Rationale for changing syntax to make DELETE call in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So Rails 7 changed the way that JavaScript is handled, replacing the [UJS functionality with `turbo` components](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#replacements-for-rails-ujs-functionality).
As part of this change, the syntax to create a link that emits a DELETE request has changed.

Rails 6 example:

`<%= link_to 'Delete', author_path(author), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>`

Rails 7 example:

`<%= link_to 'Delete', author_path(author), data: {turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>`

This means that during an update to Rails 7 all these types of calls using the `link_to` helper need to be identified and adapted.
DHH has written a [blog post](https://world.hey.com/dhh/rails-7-will-have-three-great-answers-to-javascript-in-2021-8d68191b) on the changes, but I don't see the rationale that necessitates the changed syntax in the `link_to` helper here.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Well Rails 7 and Turbo are two different things. If you want Turbo to pick certain data they need to be written explicitly for Turbo. For example you can still use UJS with Rails 7 and keep the old syntax... (Not sure if my answer makes sense or if I read your question correctly though)

Comment: @Maxence Then I probably missed the possibility of including UJS with Rails 7. Is there a low-friction way / blog post that is recommended? Thanks!